# Search Server 2010 Express with full SQL Server 2008

Tags: windows, sql-server, sql-server-2008, search-server

By default, **standalone** installation mode of Search Server 2010 Express automatically installs SQL Server 2008 **Express**.

Is it possible to use standalone mode with **full** SQL Server 2008, **not** Express? Or I should install Search Server in Server Farm mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a SQL Server other than the pre-installed SQL Server 2008 Express, you must install Search Server in server farm mode.